# How to Generate a PDF using NodeJs, EJS and MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, pdf

I'm doing a web project and I need to generate a PDF with data from MySQL, I got the connection and trough a Res.Render('Myview.ejs', data: data) I can see the data, but I want a pdf with the data.

Where i got the DB Conection and SQL Query

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

exports.proyectosHome =  (req, res) => {  
// Parámetros de conexión a la base de datos.
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database : 'tasker'
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  con.query("select * from proyectos", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err; 
    res.render('index.ejs',
    {
      datos :result
    });

  })
});
}
```

And myView Where i got a tag `<a>` that when i press, I want to create a pdf with the `select * from proyectos` data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <% for( let i = 0; i < datos.length; i++ ) { %>
    <%- datos[i].nombre %>
    <% } %>

    <a href="#">Create PDF</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, O. Jones, but I want to create a pdf from MySQL pressing the <a> tag, in the browser is just for information to the user... But I want the information from MySQL. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a formatting engine to make a nice looking PDF to download. You can use e.g. react-pdf to https://react-pdf.org/ to generate PDFs. If you're familiar with react, it is fairly straight forward, but you need to design the page using Views, similar to div.

Comment: thank you.. I used Html-PDF is the easier in Node.Js... I read a tutorial and everything OK... Thank you!